# How to append the sum of keys of each dictionary to another key?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, sum

I have a json format like below:-

```
l = {'itc': 'ball','classes': [{'scores': [{'len': 89,'width':50},{'len': 27,'width': 17}]},
             {'scores': [{'len': 90,'width': 44},{'len': 0,'width': 0}]},
             {'scores': [{'len': 50,'width': 26},{'len': 0,'width': 0}]}]}
```

Now I want to create a new list of dictionaries. like below:-

```
output= [{'result': [{'len': 89, 'width': 50}, {'len': 27, 'width': 17}], 'total': 116}, {'result': [{'len': 90, 'width': 44}, {'len': 0, 'width': 0}], 'total': 90}, {'result': [{'len': 50, 'width': 26}, {'len': 0, 'width': 0}], 'total': 50}]
```

I was able to divide the values and was able to place in the required format but I am not able to append the total score key 'len' of every dictionary in to the `total` of every dictionary result. It is calculating the whole values of all the dictionaries. The code and the output I got is as follows:-

```
added=[]
output=[]
for k,v in l.items():
    if k=='classes':
        for i in v:
            for ke,ve in i.items():
                if ke=='scores':
                    for j in ve:
                        for key,val in j.items():
                            if key=='len':
                                add = val
                                added.append(add)
            sumed=sum(added)
            out={'result':ve,'total':sumed}
            output.append(out)
print(output)
```

Output I got:-

```
[{'result': [{'len': 89, 'width': 50}, {'len': 27, 'width': 17}], 'total': 116}, {'result': [{'len': 90, 'width': 44}, {'len': 0, 'width': 0}], 'total': 206}, {'result': [{'len': 50, 'width': 26}, {'len': 0, 'width': 0}], 'total': 256}]
```

As you could see that its summing up all the values and appending them to key `total`. How do I append sum of each dictionary `score` to the `total` key of each dictionary `result` as below?

```
output= [{'result': [{'len': 89, 'width': 50}, {'len': 27, 'width': 17}], 'total': 116}, {'result': [{'len': 90, 'width': 44}, {'len': 0, 'width': 0}], 'total': 90}, {'result': [{'len': 50, 'width': 26}, {'len': 0, 'width': 0}], 'total': 50}]
```

Comment: @DaniMesejo sum of len(89+27 =116)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) to get the total:

```
res = [{"result" : cl["scores"], "total" :  sum(d["len"] for d in cl["scores"])} for cl in l["classes"]]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[{'result': [{'len': 89, 'width': 50}, {'len': 27, 'width': 17}], 'total': 116}, {'result': [{'len': 90, 'width': 44}, {'len': 0, 'width': 0}], 'total': 90}, {'result': [{'len': 50, 'width': 26}, {'len': 0, 'width': 0}], 'total': 50}]
```

Or the equivalent, for-loop:

```
res = []
for cl in l["classes"]:
    scores = cl["scores"]
    total = sum(d["len"] for d in cl["scores"])
    res.append({"result": scores, "total": total})
```